# I am getting null pointer exception on line 12 ( accIds.add(a.Id);)even though there are records , could anyone help me with it , Thanks In Advance

Tags: apex, batch

```
public class batchClassOnContacts implements
database.Batchable<Sobject> {
    public  List<Account> listOfAccounts;
    
    public  Map<Id , List<Contact>> sizeOfContacts;
    
    Public  List<Id> accIds;
    public batchClassOnContacts(List<Account> accList){
         
        System.debug('Entered Constructor');
        this.listOfAccounts = accList; 
        System.debug('ListOfAccounts'+listOfAccounts);
        if(accList != null){
            for(Account a : accList){
                System.debug('a is '+a);
                accIds.add(a.Id);
                
                System.debug('accIds are'+this.accIds);
            }}
        
    }
    
    
    public database.QueryLocator start(database.BatchableContext bx){
        System.debug('Entered start');
        return database.getQueryLocator([select id ,accountId from contact where accountId in : this.accIds]);
        //Code here
    }
    public  void execute(database.BatchableContext bx ,list<Contact> contactList){
        System.debug('Entered Execute');
        System.debug('listOfContacts'+contactList);
        //Map<Id ,List<Contact>> finalMap = new Map<Id ,List<Contact>>();
        if(this.listOfAccounts != null){ 
            for(Account a :listOfAccounts){
                List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
                if(contactList != null){
                    for(Contact c : contactList){
                        if(a.Id == c.AccountId){
                            if(this.sizeOfContacts.keySet().contains(c.AccountId)){
                                this.sizeOfContacts.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
                            }
                            else{
                                contacts.add(c);
                                this.sizeOfContacts.put(A.Id , contacts);
                            }            
                        }             
                    }
                }
                
            }}
        
        
        // sizeOfContacts = finalMap;
        System.debug('sizeOfContacts are'+this.sizeOfContacts);
    }
    
    public  void finish(database.BatchableContext bx){
        System.debug('Entered Final');
        List<Account> accountListToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        if(this.sizeOfContacts != null){
            for(Id I : this.sizeOfContacts.keyset()){
                for(Account a : this.ListOfAccounts){
                    if(I == a.Id){
                        a.Number_Of_Contacts__c = this.sizeOfContacts.get(I).size();
                        accountListToUpdate.add(a);
                    }
                }   
                if(accountListToUpdate != null){
                    update accountListToUpdate;  
                }           
                
            }
        }
        
    }  }
```

Comment: Hello, I think you have to instantiate the list  accIds    `public batchClassOnContacts(List<Account> accList){
accIds = new List<Id>();`

Comment: did you try debugging the value of addIds before the NPE line

Comment: Hi Guys , Thanks for the response , Please find below code which I am writing in Anonymous window

List<Account> accList = [select Id from Account where Id = :'0015i00000N9dB8AAJ'];
database.executeBatch(new batchClassOnContacts(accList), 1);

I could see the data from line 11 [Account Id] , which means there is data in variable a  even though its throwing null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
accIds.add(a.Id);
```

You never actually initialized `accIds`, so it is null, and throws `NullPointerException` when you try to use a method on it.

Before trying to use it, you need to initialize it, like so:

```
public batchClassOnContacts(List<Account> accList){
    System.debug('Entered Constructor');
    accIds = new List<Id>();
    this.listOfAccounts = accList; 
    System.debug('ListOfAccounts'+listOfAccounts);
    if(accList != null){
        for(Account a : accList){
            System.debug('a is '+a);
            accIds.add(a.Id);
            
            System.debug('accIds are'+this.accIds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denver , That works..!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the colon from

```
List<Account> accList = [select Id from Account where Id = :'0015i00000N9dB8AAJ'];
```

colon works for variable

and

```
if(accList != null){
    for(Account a : accList){
       System.debug('a is '+a);
       accIds.add(a.Id);
       System.debug('accIds are'+this.accIds);
    }
}
```

use `accList.size()>0` instead of `acclist != null`

Comment: The check against `accList`, if a check is used at all, should indeed be for `!= null` in this case (the list passed into the method could be null).

Comment: `:` using inline queries actually executes Apex code; it can indeed be a string, or a number, or even a method! Also, the check for null is the only one you need; it is valid behavior to loop over an empty list.